# Compare mutiple ids present in list of dictionaries with the ids of model django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-mysql

How can i make an efficient django orm query, which will compare ids from the list of dictionaries with the ids as foreign key in other model, e.g i have two models

```
Product:

product_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

ProductOrder:

order_status=models.BooleanField()
product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

now i want extract every product which is present in product order.

in simple query i can do this way:

```
prod=ProductOrder.objects.all()
products=Product.objects.all()
for prod in prod:
  for products in products:
   if prod.product==products.id:
        # save product
```

Is there any way to get this through one query or more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(productorder__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Here `products` is a `QuerySet` of `Product`s for which there is at least one related `ProductOrder`.

This works because we make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `ProductOrder` table and then check if that `ProductOrder` is not `NULL`. We use [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent retrieving a `Product` that many times as there are `ProductOrder`s. Likely the Django ORM will notice the `__isnull=False` constraint, and optimize this to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: got it, and its more easy!